# How to create a bootstrap accordion menu on drupal 8

Tags: bootstrap-4, twig, accordion, drupal-8, sidebar

Hello I'm attempting to build an accordion menu on Drupal 8, but need a little help figuring out how to write out the correct structure with the correct data targets for the dynamic menu.

I've tried searching stackoverflow, but couldn't quite find the correct answer. I'm trying to implement the basic card style accordion found on the bootstrap documentation. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#accordion-example

Below is the code I would like to modify, this works for bootstrap dropdowns, but we specifically need accordion functionality to work, rather than dropdowns.

```html
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a menu.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - menu_name: The machine name of the menu.
 * - items: A nested list of menu items. Each menu item contains:
 *   - attributes: HTML attributes for the menu item.
 *   - below: The menu item child items.
 *   - title: The menu link title.
 *   - url: The menu link url, instance of \Drupal\Core\Url
 *   - localized_options: Menu link localized options.
 *   - is_expanded: TRUE if the link has visible children within the current
 *     menu tree.
 *   - is_collapsed: TRUE if the link has children within the current menu tree
 *     that are not currently visible.
 *   - in_active_trail: TRUE if the link is in the active trail. 
 *
 * @ingroup templates
 */
#}
{% import _self as menus %}

{#
  We call a macro which calls itself to render the full tree.
  @see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html
#}
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <ul id="menu" {{ attributes.addClass('navbar-list','menu', 'nav', 'navbar-nav') }}>
    {% else %}
      <ul {{ attributes.addClass('dropdown-menu') }}>
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
        {%
        set classes = [
        'navbar-item',
        item.is_expanded ? 'menu-item--expanded',
        item.is_expanded ? 'dropdown',
        item.is_collapsed ? 'menu-item--collapsed',
        item.in_active_trail ? 'menu-item--active-trail',
        item.in_active_trail ? 'active',
        ]
        %}
      {% if menu_level == 0 and item.is_expanded %}
        <li{{ item.attributes.addClass( classes,'expanded', 'dropdown') }}>
        <a href="{{ item.url }}" class="navbar-link dropdown-toggle" data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> {{ item.title }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
      {% else %}
        <li{{ item.attributes.addClass( classes,'item') }}> 
        {#{{ link(item.title, item.url) }}#} 
        {{ link(item.title, item.url, { 'class':['navbar-link']}) }}
      {% endif %}
      {% if item.below %}
        {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes.removeClass('nav', 'navbar-nav'), menu_level + 1) }}
      {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

I'd like this to output the same as the dropdowns in the bootstrap docs. Any help would be appreciated! Much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```html
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
  
  {% set ip = 1 %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <ul{{ attributes.addClass('nav navbar-nav').setAttribute('id', 'accordion') }}>
    {% else %}
      <ul class="sub-menu card-body">
   
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
      {%
        set classes = [
          menu_level ? 'sub-item' : 'nav-item',
          item.in_active_trail ? 'active',
          item.below ? 'card',
        ]
      %}
      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        {%
          set link_classes = [
            not menu_level ? 'nav-link',
            item.in_active_trail ? 'active',
            item.url.getOption('attributes').class ? item.url.getOption('attributes').class | join(' '),
            'nav-link-' ~ item.url.toString() | clean_class,
          ]
        %}
        {% if item.below %}
  {% if item.in_active_trail %}
  <div class="card-header" id="heading{{ip}}">
  <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{ip}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse{{ip}}">
             
          {{ item.title }}
         </button>
   </div>

   <div id="collapse{{ip}}" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading{{ip}}" data-parent="#accordion">
    {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
    {% else %}
    <div class="card-header" id="heading{{ip}}">
  <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{ip}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse{{ip}}">
             
          {{ item.title }}
         </button>
   </div>

   <div id="collapse{{ip}}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading{{ip}}" data-parent="#accordion">
    {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
   {% endif %} 
  {% set ip = ip + 1 %}  
  </div>
        {% else %}
          {{ link(item.title, item.url, {'class': link_classes}) }}
    
        {% endif %}
  
      </li>
 
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```